# System.Linq.Dynamic - Can I use IN clause in WHERE statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic

I have dynamic linq WHERE statement:

```
dataContext.Table.Where("id = 0 Or id = 1 Or id = 2 Or ...");
```

I want change to:

```
dataContext.Table.Where("id IN (0, 1, 2, ...)");
```

But it doesn´t work. How can I do this for better performance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [How to use “contains” or “like” in a dynamic linq query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2456070/145999)

```
//edit: this is probably broken, see below
ids = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
dataContext.Table.Where("id.Contains(@0)", ids);
```

Aside: It is good practice to use placeholders in dynamic linq expressions. Otherwise you may open yourself to linq injection attacks ([Is Injection Possible through Dynamic LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022254/145999))

---

EDIT:

actually I think I messed this up. 
Unfortunately I cannot test this at the moment.
But I think the correct syntax in this case should be `dataContext.Table.Where("@0.Contains(id)",ids);`, not the other way around, and that version does **not** work out-of-the-box.

See [here](http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html) for a way to add this functionality to dynamic link. You need to modify the library for this.

Answer (score 6):

```
var ids = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
dataContext.Table.Where(f => ids.Contains(f.id))
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but column name "id" is changing. I get this column dinamycally. So I can´t use static Linq. I have to use dynamic linq library for string where clausule as example. [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: @Ingenu, read the resource and you will find out what Dynamic Linq is about

Answer (score 4):

it seems that in version 1.0.4 of System.Linq.Dynamic , we can use the following syntax `dataContext.Table.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.id)",ids);` as it was made and presented in the already cited blog:
[here](http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html)

Comment: It seems that for string values, ids has to be a List<string>, and **not** an array, otherwise you get the error "No 'it' is in scope"