# Dynamic Linq Where IN

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

How could I define a `where in` criteria with `Dynamic Linq`?

I tired workaround below but it must not work, because it doesn't make sense!

```
context.Records.Where("@0.Contains(ID)", new object[]{
   new string[] {"1", "2", "3"}
}); // throws error No property or field 'ID' exists in type 'String'
```

**Edit 1:**

Thanks to everybody, All you need is to use `it` or `outerIt` keyword in your `Dynamic.Linq` query, so in my example i just need to use `outerIt`:

```
context.Records.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.ID)", new object[]{
   new string[] {"1", "2", "3"}
});
```

You can find more example and information here: [Advanced Linq - Dynamic Linq query library: Add support for 'Contains' extension](http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html)

Comment: Are you working with EntityFramework?

Comment: You don't need that. Use `context.Records.Where(x => list.Contains(x.ID)`

Comment: @OleksandrNahirniak yes.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I need to use Dynamic Linq

Comment: I don't see how, your question shows an extremely basic use of linq

Comment: A more updated version which also supports .NET Core can be found at https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other folks here introduced interesting workarounds but they are not useful if we use `Dynamic.Linq` library. **Oleksandr Nahirniak** [found this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186683/system-linq-dynamic-can-i-use-in-clause-in-where-statement). There is also a blog post about advanced Linq queries with `Dynamic.Linq` which reviewd[here](http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html).

Since version `1.0.4` the library also supports `Contains` extension as well. It could be done just like below:

```
 query = Contact.GetContactsList()
                .AsQueryable()
                .Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.Country)", new List<String>() { "Austria", "Poland" });
```

or

```
query = Contact.GetContactsList()
               .AsQueryable()
               .Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.Country) && it.BirthDate.Year > @1", new List<string>() { "Austria", "Poland" }, 1955);
```

there are two keywords `it` and `outerIt`. It represent to the list that you have passed as a parameter and `outerIt` represent the collection itself.

So here is my working example:

```
context.Records.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.ID)", new object[]{
   new string[] {"1", "2", "3"}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you work with EF you can use direct sql commands, like:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM Records AS r WHERE r.{dynamicPropertyName} IN @ids", new string[] {"1", "2", "3"});
```

**EDIT**

Solved:

[System.Linq.Dynamic - Can I use IN clause in WHERE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186683/system-linq-dynamic-can-i-use-in-clause-in-where-statement)

Comment: Why write SQL when you can use `Contains` for this?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto How I understood topic starter's question, you don't know (in runtime/dynamic) which property do you want apply for IN operation. In other cases linq more preferable totally.

Comment: You can do so using dynamic LINQ (by using a couple of `Expression`s) without resorting to writing SQL by hand, which entirely defeats the purpose of using EF in the first place

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto oh, yep, make sense, you are right, thanks

Comment: The link you provided helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own extension method `In`, here's the IEnumerable:

```
public static class ExtLinq
    {
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> In<TSource, TMember>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TMember> identifier, params TMember[] values) =>
         source.Where(m => values.Contains(identifier(m)));
    }
```

use it like this:

```
context.Records.In(x => x.ID, 1, 2, 3)
```

if you want the `IN` to be executed on server to save data travels, use this IQueryable version, implemented with expressions API:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> In<TSource, TMember>(this IQueryable<TSource> source,
   Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> identifier, params TMember[] values)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "m");
            var inExpression = GetExpression(parameter, identifier, values);
            var theExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(inExpression, parameter);
            return source.Where(theExpression);
        }
static Expression GetExpression<TSource, TMember>(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> identifier, IEnumerable<TMember> values)
        {
            var memberName = (identifier.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
            var member = Expression.Property(parameter, memberName);
            var valuesConstant = Expression.Constant(values.ToList());
            MethodInfo method = typeof(List<TMember>).GetMethod("Contains");
            Expression call = Expression.Call(valuesConstant, method, member);
            return call;
        }
```

this query (or similar depening on your table) will be executed on server and return desired data:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[Records] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get same results by creating a simple extension method like so:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T src, params T[] items)
    {
        return items.Contains(src);
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
context.Records.Where(record => record.In("1", "2", "3"));
```

Comment: That's correct but I'm using `Dynamic.Linq` library, so I cannot use workaround above.