# Dynamic LINQ's OrderBy Injection dangerous?

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I've made the ability to sort page content dynamically through two query strings and dynamic LINQ. Today I just realized I can use this in an unintended way.

**Intended**

Typically I would provide the query string parameters `Sort.Field=SomeField` and `Sort.Direction=desc` and this would allow the sorting to be set via `query.OrderBy(field + " " + direction)` in the code.

**Unintended**

Today I learned I can provide something like `Sort.Field=Modified.On != null ? Modified.On : Created.On` and `Sort.Direction=desc`.

Being able to do this isn't dangerous itself, but it has left me feeling a bit uneasy as to what is possible with Dynamic LINQ.

Are there any other security issues that can occur that I never intended, via this injections of sorts?

**Note**

I did read this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738953/is-injection-possible-through-dynamic-linq?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but that seems to be more aimed at escaping characters, where my concern is what dynamic LINQ's `OrderBy` function is capable of.

Comment: Starting to think that it's not going to be as dangerous as I first thought, since this will be using LINQ to SQL the user won't even be able to do a simple `Sort.Field=Modified.On.ToString()` so they're restricted to actions that LINQ to SQL will allow. Still not sure of the scope of that though.

Comment: LINQ is different than string concatenation. When you send a raw SQL query to the server, the server parses that query into commands. The danger is not properly protecting your string concatenation and allowing a malicious actor to inject commands into your original query. With LINQ you are building up a sequence of code items via control flow in your own code. These code items aren't parsed by an interpreter; rather the code items are converted into equivalent SQL. So one cannot inject foreign commands into your query because you've effectively hard-coded the possible query(ies) in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the worst they could do is figure out a field name you aren't displaying and sort by it. Tried doing some stuff like `Sort.Field=new Timestamp()` and it just gave me `syntax error` so I think my worries might have been for nothing.

Comment: @KennethK.You should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @KennethK. "one cannot inject foreign commands into your query " that's not completely true. If you use dynamic linq for `Where` for example - one can inject foreign (LINQ) commands if you are not careful (not using parameters, just like with sql injections).

Comment: @Evk I may be misunderstanding "dynamic LINQ" then. I've understood dynamic LINQ to be continually building up IQueryables until you finally execute a `ToList`/`ToArray` (i.e. force query execution).

Comment: @KennethK. dynamic linq, at least in context of this question, is when you pass raw strings to linq functions (like `.Where("UserID = 1")`) and they are parsed to expressions. There are several libraries for that, like 'System.Linq.Dynamic'.

Comment: @Evk OK, then I agree that a similar security concern exists.